# How to Display ReportHeader Text label only once?

Tags: crystal-reports

In the sub report

```
Fruit
apple    10x1    10
Fruit
banana   2x2     4
```

The label Fruit keeps on repeating how can I make it appear once

```
Fruit
apple    10x1    10
banana   2x2     4
```

I put it on the the report header and I already done creating supress formula for it where I put ---> not onfirstrecord in supress but it not working either onfirstrecord (it disappears). I also tried puttingit in GroupHeader but still it doesn't work.

both fruits as I check seems to be both same recordnumber I dont know why.

Comment: what is your design?

Comment: Done I put it in the report footer

Comment: Why not add it to the sub report itself.